# Index a dataframe by 2 vectors of row and column coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe

My problem is simple, and I figure there's a solution for it in R, but I can't find it anywhere. Example below:

```
mydf = data.frame(a = letters[1:6], 
                  b = letters[7:12], 
                  c = letters[13:18])

rows = c(1,3,5)
cols = c(1,2,2)
```

using the data above, I want to return a vector that has the values of `mydf` in locations `(1,1)`, `(3,2)`, and `(5,2)`, which would be `c('a', 'i', 'k')`.

Comment: `mydf[cbind(rows, cols)]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, not very elegant, but you could use sapply, defining an anonymous function:

`sapply(1:length(rows), function(z){mydf[rows[z], cols[z]]})`

Same result as the more readable but less efficient for loop:

```
result <- NULL
for(counter in 1:length(rows){
result <- c(result, mydf[rows[counter], cols[counter]]
 }
```

Also make sure your col classes aren't factors, otherwise it will return a factor. In your example you could have added.

`..., stringsAsFactors = F)`

Or use `as.vector()` over the result.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is like this

diag(as.matrix(mydf[rows,cols]))

note the diag works only for a matrix